# When does status.lastScheduleTime change?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm working on a Kubernetes CronJob that relies on knowing when the last successfull run happened in order to correctly notify users about new events since said run. That said, I need to know if I can rely on `status.lastScheduleTime` to be my "last successful run" timestamp.

When does it change? Does it depend on exit codes? Is it even a good idea to use it for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't rely on that as an indicator of a successful run. That value changes whenever your CronJob runs. It doesn't mean that it's your last successful run and it doesn't change depending on exit codes.

A [`CronJob`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) essentially runs a [`Job`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) with a name that is `<cronjob name>-<unix epoch>`. The [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is in Unix/Linux what you would get from the `date +%s` command, for example, also that epoch is a timestamp that is slightly later than the timestamp of the `lastScheduleTime` (It's when the job resource gets created)

To find out if your last cron job ran successfully you can do something like the following.

You can get the last Job run/started name including its epoch with something like this:

```
$ kubectl get jobs | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Then after that, you could check whether that job is successful with something like:

```
$ kubectl get job <job-name> -o=jsonpath='{.status.succeeded}'
```

Should return a `1`.